# Searching dependent criterias from database

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

Hello I am writing a code where people can search activities from database by using jsp. When I execute the program, I can search according to type,description,location,city and date successfully. I can see datas on page. But when I fill two or three criteria or etc. , program is not working very well. For example, if I fill type as 'Music' and city as 'Istanbul' , program finds all music activities and all activities in İstanbul. I think my sql query is wrong. If I change query as OR, I have to fill all fields. Otherwise it is returning empty table. But user can fill two criteria or three criteria or etc. It depends on the user. If user fill type as 'Music' and city as 'Istanbul' the proram must display only music activities in Istanbul. How can I fix ? What will be the correct code ? 
[image]

[image]

search.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body background="http://www.teamarking.com/barcode/bar_background.jpg"> 
    <form method="post" action="reservations.jsp">

        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Book Ticket</title>
    </head>

    <center>    
        <table border="1" width="30%" height="30%">
            <th><font color='#D18603'>id</font>
            <th><font color='#D18603'>Type</font></th>
            <th><font color='#D18603'>Description</font></th>
            <th><font color='#D18603'>City</font></th>
            <th><font color='#D18603'>Location</font></th>
            <th><font color='#D18603'>Date</font></th>
            <th><font color='#D18603'>Price</font></th>
            <th><font color='#D18603'>Time</font></th>

            <th><font color='#D18603'>Buy</font>





                <%
                    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/users", "users", "123");

                    Statement st = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs;

                    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from activities where type=? OR description=? OR city=? OR  location=? OR date=? OR time=?");
                    ps.setString(1, request.getParameter("type"));
                    ps.setString(2, request.getParameter("description"));
                    ps.setString(3, request.getParameter("city"));
                    ps.setString(4, request.getParameter("location"));
                    ps.setString(5, request.getParameter("date"));
                    ps.setString(6, request.getParameter("time"));

                    rs = ps.executeQuery();
                    while (rs.next()) {

                        out.println("<tr>");
                        out.println("<form action='reservations.jsp'>");
                        out.println("<td>" + rs.getString("id") + "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='" + rs.getString("id") + "'></td>");
                        out.println("<td>" + rs.getString("type") + "<input type='hidden' name='type' value='" + rs.getString("type") + "'></td>");
                        out.println("<td>" + rs.getString("description") + "<input type='hidden' name='description' value='" + rs.getString("description") + "'></td>");
                        out.println("<td>" + rs.getString("city") + "<input type='hidden' name='city' value='" + rs.getString("city") + "'></td>");
                        out.println("<td>" + rs.getString("location") + "<input type='hidden' name='location' value='" + rs.getString("location") + "'></td>");
                        out.println("<td>" + rs.getString("date") + "<input type='hidden' name='date' value='" + rs.getString("date") + "'></td>");
                        out.println("<td>" + rs.getString("price") + "<input type='hidden' name='price' value='" + rs.getString("price") + "'></td>");
                        out.println("<td>" + rs.getString("time") + "<input type='hidden' name='time' value='" + rs.getString("time") + "'></td>");

                        out.println("<td><b><form action='reservations.jsp'><select name='buy'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option></select><input type='submit' value='Submit'></form></b>");

                        out.println("</tr>");

                    }
                    st.close();

                %>


                </center>
        </table>

        <br>  <br><a href='success.jsp'>Back</a>
        <br><br><a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wanna create the sql dynamically like this:

```
String type = request.getParameter("type");
String description = request.getParameter("description");
String city = request.getParameter("city");
String location = request.getParameter("location");
String date = request.getParameter("date");
String time = request.getParameter("time");

// Check all the parameters for potential SQL injection attack here

StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("Select * from activities where 1 = 1");
if(type != null && type.trim().length() != 0)
    sql.append(" and type = '").append(type).append("'");
if(description != null && description.trim().length() != 0)
    sql.append(" and description = '").append(description).append("'");
if(city != null && city.trim().length() != 0)
    sql.append(" and city = '").append(city).append("'");
if(location != null && location.trim().length() != 0)
    sql.append(" and location = '").append(location).append("'");
if(date != null && date.trim().length() != 0)
    sql.append(" and date = '").append(date).append("'");
if(time != null && time.trim().length() != 0)
    sql.append(" and time= '").append(time).append("'");

Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql.toString());
```

Comment: When ı execute like you said it returns emoty table @GurwinderSingh

Comment: Ideally it should work. Most possible cause is data though I can't be really sure. Why don't you post some sample data in the question and what output you expect out of it.

Comment: ı wrote. for example if user enter in type as 'music' music datas come, if user enter in city as Istanbul. Activities in istanbul should come. now it is working but when user both enter music and istanbul, other activities other cities are coming

Comment: can you help me for fixing my problem

Comment: i have to fill all fields in your algorithm. But ı want to that user can fill just one field or just two field. In order to run your code, user have to fill all fields